Is it possible to grab a value from a blob (uploaded csv to container) and pass it to a Logic App?
I'm trying to add a dynamic distribution list to an email I send out with a logic app. It's triggered whenever a blob is uploaded into a container it is watching.
Is it possible to:

grab a value from the csv and enter it into the email that is being composed.
Is it possible to exclude this column when it is being attached in the email?

For example if the csv were to be composed like so:
+----+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+
| ID | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Distribution List  |
+----+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+
| 1  | 500     | R       | 500     | fakeemail@fake.com |
+----+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+
| 2  | 600     | R       | 600     | fakeemail@fake.com |
+----+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+
| 3  | 700     | DED     | NULL    | fakeemail@fake.com |
+----+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+

I need the value in the distribution list column to go here:

The distribution list would only be there for the purpose of building the email, is there a way to remove it before the blob content is attached?
EDIT: Parse_JSON Schema:
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "ID": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Column1": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Column2": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Column3": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "DistributionList": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "ID",
            "Column1",
            "Column2",
            "Column3",
            "DistributionList"
        ]
    }
}


Yes, it’s possible but there’s no simple answer to your question. You just gotta put the Lego pieces together.

I have used given workflow to pass the distribution list name in the email and then removed the column before attaching it to the email.


I have used below JavaScript code to parse the csv data to JSON.
Parsed the JSON array and then used Select action to fetch the required columns and  lastly used Create CSV table action to form a CSV table which will be used as an email attachment.
const csvData = workflowContext.actions.Get_blob_content_V2.outputs.body; // Blob content as a string


const lines = csvData.trim().split('\n');
const result = [];

if (lines.length === 0) {
    return result; 
}

const headers = lines[0].split(',').map(header => header.trim());

for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const obj = {};
    const currentLine = lines[i].split(',').map(field => field.trim());

    for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        obj[headers[j]] = currentLine[j];
    }
    result.push(obj);
}

return result;

Code-
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Create_CSV_table": {
                "inputs": {
                    "format": "CSV",
                    "from": "@body('Select')"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Select": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Table"
            },
            "Execute_JavaScript_Code": {
                "inputs": {
                    "code": "const csvData = workflowContext.actions.Get_blob_content_V2.outputs.body; // Blob content as a string\r\n\r\n\r\nconst lines = csvData.trim().split('\\n');\r\nconst result = [];\r\n\r\nif (lines.length === 0) {\r\n    return result; \r\n}\r\n\r\nconst headers = lines[0].split(',').map(header => header.trim());\r\n\r\nfor (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {\r\n    const obj = {};\r\n    const currentLine = lines[i].split(',').map(field => field.trim());\r\n\r\n    for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {\r\n        obj[headers[j]] = currentLine[j];\r\n    }\r\n    result.push(obj);\r\n}\r\n\r\nreturn result;\r\n"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_blob_content_V2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "JavaScriptCode"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": {
                                "Attachments": [
                                    {
                                        "ContentBytes": "@{base64(body('Create_CSV_table'))}",
                                        "Name": "@triggerBody()?['Name']"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "Body": "<p class=\"editor-paragraph\">Test Email.....</p>",
                                "Importance": "Normal",
                                "Subject": "CSV file",
                                "To": "@items('For_each')['Distribution List']"
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['outlook']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/v2/Mail"
                        },
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@outputs('Parse_JSON')['body']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Create_CSV_table": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Get_blob_content_V2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(triggerBody()?['Path']))}/content",
                    "queries": {
                        "inferContentType": true
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmdGVzdCUyZlRlc3QxMi5jc3Y=": "/test/Test12.csv"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@outputs('Execute_JavaScript_Code')?['body']",
                    "schema": {
                        "items": {
                            "properties": {
                                "Column1": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Column2": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Column3": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Distribution List": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "ID": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "ID",
                                "Column1",
                                "Column2",
                                "Column3",
                                "Distribution List"
                            ],
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Execute_JavaScript_Code": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Select": {
                "inputs": {
                    "from": "@outputs('Execute_JavaScript_Code')?['body']",
                    "select": {
                        "Column1": "@item()?['Column1']",
                        "Column2": "@item()?['Column2']",
                        "Column3": "@item()?['Column3']",
                        "ID": "@item()?['ID']"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Select"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_blob_is_added_or_modified_(properties_only)_(V2)": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Second",
                    "interval": 10
                },
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/triggers/batch/onupdatedfile",
                    "queries": {
                        "checkBothCreatedAndModifiedDateTime": false,
                        "folderId": "JTJmdGVzdA==",
                        "maxFileCount": 10
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmdGVzdA==": "/test"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Second",
                    "interval": 10
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/0e8****b5e7c/resourceGroups/*****/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/0e8*******5e7c/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/azureblob"
                },
                "outlook": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/0e8****b5e7c/resourceGroups/*****/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/outlook",
                    "connectionName": "outlook",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/0e89*******8b5e7c/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/outlook"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This gives me expected response.




Thank you for your response! I'm looking to accomplish this in a way where there would not need to be any more manual input from me if the csv was structured differently, but always had a "Distribution List" column. It's my understanding that parsing the JSON needs a schema to work which would needed to be generated by me. Is what I'm asking achievable?

I'm also receiving an error for some reason
{"error":{"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"The template validation failed: 'The action(s) 'Get_blob_content_V2' referenced by 'inputs' in action 'Execute_JavaScript_Code' are not defined in the template.'."}} 

although I've constructed it similarly. Any ideas what could be going wrong here?

disregard previous error- logic app is compiled correctly. Although I'm receiving this error in the "Parse JSON" activity Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Parse_JSON' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language expression 'outputs('Execute_JavaScript_Code')?['body']' cannot be evaluated because property 'body' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an integer index. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.

@BlakeB9 You need to add the schema for Parse_JSON action once for the input body. Please check the output, you are getting after executing javascript action. It should have an array of body in the output

I took the output from the javascript action and generated a schema in the Parse_JSON action, but I'm still receiving the same error

@BlakeB9 Share the output of javascript action and also screenshot of your Parse json action with the input and schema

  {
    "ID": "1",
    "Column1": "500",
    "Column2": "R",
    "Column3": "500",
    "DistributionList": "fakeemail@fake.com"
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "Column1": "600",
    "Column2": "R",
    "Column3": "600",
    "DistributionList": "fakeemail@fake.com"
  },
  {
    "ID": "3",
    "Column1": "700",
    "Column2": "DED",
    "Column3": "NULL",
    "DistributionList": "fakeemail@fake.com"
  }
]``` Here is the output of the javascript action

You should get the output with body parameter in it from javascript code. Are you using workflowContext.actions.Get_blob_content_V2.outputs.body in JavaScript as an input data?

Yes I am. The parse json shows no input(because it looks like it can't get the input from the error message). I will update my post with the schema. Too long to post here

Ah, believe I've figured it out. I needed to change the content/input to outputs('Execute_Javascript_Code') so basically take that ?['body'] part out

@BlakeB9 Glad it worked for you

Yes,
It's a long question but yu can achieve all of it.
1. You can fetch email from CSV and add it to the email. You just need to Parse it to a JSON first. You can use this sample strategy.


2. You can exclude this column when attaching to email by creating a parsed CSV. You can do it by this strategy. Pass your JSON of qualifying values to this connector. The output can be attached to the email as File Content.



Thank you for your response! I'm looking to accomplish this in a way where there would not need to be any more manual input from me if the csv was structured differently, but always had a "Distribution List" column. It's my understanding that parsing the JSON needs a schema to work which would needed to be generated by me. As well as other things here which will work, but only for this specific csv, while I expect to be receiving differently structured csv's in this container. Is what I'm asking achievable?

No, the schema is required but you dont need to map it. You can but {} in the schema section to achieve dynamic mapping. You can also use removeProperty() function to exclude the Distribution List in runtime so you will not have to manually edit the schema everytime. You can also put value based scanning by removing the field which contains '@' (finding the emails)

Thank you, and sorry I'm a bit unfamiliar, where can I add the removeProperty() function to remove the distribution list column?

I've figured out how to use removeProperty() and I'm trying to use it when adding an attachment to the email, although when I use it on the Parse JSON activity I'm getting an error for it being an array. And when I use it on the Create CSV table activity it is telling me that it's a String. It's expecting an object, do you know how I could solve this issue?
